# How to solver the least square problem involves with the variable is the product of Hadamard Product?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I encounted an least square problem involves hadamard product of two $100\times 1$ matrix: X, Y:
$$
A_{N\times100}*(X_{100\times 1}∘Y_{100\times 1})_{100\times 1} = B_{N\times 1} 
$$
In above equation, * is a traditional matrix multiplication, ∘is the hadamard product. A and B are observed known matrix， X is also known . I known this is  non-convex problem.
My question: is there any method to get an approximate anser of Y?

Comment: The pseudoinverse $A^+$ and 
Hadamard multiplication/division $\{\odot/\oslash\}$
can solve the problem
$$\eqalign{
&A(x\odot y) = b \\
&(x\odot y) = A^+b \\
&y = (A^+b)\oslash x \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x} \circ \mathbf{x}$, a 100-by-1 vector with positive entries. The least-squares problem you are facing is now recast into a non-negative least-squares (NNLS) , i.e. minimize
$$
\phi(\mathbf{y})=\| \mathbf{Ay-b} \|^2, s.t. \mathbf{y} \ge 0
$$
Once $\mathbf{y}$ is found, take the (elementwise) square root to obtain $\mathbf{x}$

---

Let $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{x} \circ \mathbf{y}$,
Since $\mathbf{x}$ is known, the method consists in 1) solving for
$\mathbf{z}$ using standard LS and then 2) retrieve $\mathbf{y}$ by elementwise division :
$$
\mathbf{y}=\frac{\mathbf{z}_{LS}}{\mathbf{x}}
$$

Comment: Thanks Steph. You means the X∘Y transfered to X∘X?

Comment: See my edit. I had not correctly read your question at first . Now it hould be ok.

Comment: I implemented my code with the same process as your described in the edited comments. While, the result did not OK. Because, in the original version of my problem, the X, Y are both unknown. I give a initial value for X to get an make sense result. My new question is if the X, Y are both need to be solved?

Comment: In your problem formulation , the vector x was said to be known. Without further hypothesis, it is easy to see that you cannot recover in an unique manner both vectors...